# Get only the groups a user belongs to in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get only the groups to which the user belongs, but with the current code I show all the existing groups.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("My groups"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: userColeccion.doc('$userID').collection("grupos").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text("groups users"),
                Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("grupos")
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, groupSnapshot) {
                      if (groupSnapshot.hasData) {
                        var groupList = (groupSnapshot.data
                                as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>)
                            .docs
                            .map((d) => Group.fromJson(d.data()))
                            .toList();

                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: groupList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var group = groupList[index];
                            return Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(group.namegroup),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }

                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when entering "users", you can enter the id of each one, within that id there is a collection called "groups" which stores the key of the different groups to which the user belongs, with this key I intend to search in the "groups" collection that is at the "users" level, but it stores the key of the groups that exist.

collection "usuarios"

[image]

[image]

collection "grupos"

[image]

In short, I would like to show on the screen only the groups to which the user belongs, the keys are stored by the user, thank you very much for any help or explanation.

Comment: You can likely [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to filter the results, but it's impossible for us to say what field to query on at the moment. Please edit your question to show a screenshot of one of the documents that you're trying to load, and how they identify group membership.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I updated the description of the question, I was also thinking of using a query, but I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0):

To get the documents from `grupos` where `namegroup` is equal to `Grupo 2`, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

```
stream: userColeccion.doc('$userID').collection("grupos")
  .where("namegroup", "==", "Grupo 2")
  .snapshots(),
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but actually i want to be able to get only the groups where the current user, is present

Answer (score 0):

'Uid', isEqualTo:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid... in the fields also add the uid of the current so it should checking